# Как получить информацию из команды cat и записать ее в переменную?

Tags: java, android

Пишу программу,которая должна вывести на экран число из файла,который находится в папке,доступная для чтения только из под root и нужно вписать эту информацию в переменную Int(или String).
Вот такие данные имеются в данном файле:

```
M6Note:/ # cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p50
72151002
```

Эту информацию нужно считать и записать в переменную.
Каким способом можно это реализовать?

Comment: В чем конкретно заключается вопрос? Были придуманы какие то конкретные способы под реализацию конкретно вашей задачи? Ну а ответ: Любым, известным вам, способом

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
//если приложение имеет root права 
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/dev/block/mmcblk0p50");
String line = fileReader.readLine());
fileReader.close();
if(line!=null) {
  int i=Integer.parseInt(line); //складываем значение в переменную i
}
```

Только надо обложиться `try-catch`